# How open a .torrent file in miutorrent programmatically

Tags: android, utorrent

In my android app i have successfully downloaded .torrent files and now i want to open them  in miutorrent (or another torrent downloading app) how to implement this ?? any help would be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting an intent with mime type as `application/x-bittorrent`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(TorrentUri, "application/x-bittorrent");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```